# How do you render to root page in Elm?

Tags: elm

I am super Elm beginner and struggling with a following thing.

I want to render to root page after I get a HTTP response from server. (Not right after DOM event happens)

I am using Browser.application and trying to goTo function but I don’t know how it can be done.

```
-- I want to render to root page after I get a HTTP response. (Maybe this Cmd.none can be replaced by some function that renders to root page?)
GotResponse result ->
    case result of
        Ok response ->
            ( { model | response = response }, Cmd.none )

        Err _ ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "render to root page"? What is a "page"? What is the "root"? What do you mean by "rendering"? Do you want to change the URL? If so, what should happen then? Should it go back to the server to get another webpage or just render a different view in the client?

Comment: @glennsl
I am sorry for confusing you. I just wanna render a different view (It is TopPage in my application.
I just don't know how it can be done besides href onClick.

Comment: Alright, then all you really need to do here is update your model according to what your view code needs. But without knowing the model and view code it's really not possible for any of us to tell you exactly how, since that depends entirely on your own code. You mention `TopPage` though, so I would guess you have to put that into your model somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct! You'll need to do that with a command.

You probably want to use [`Browser.Navigation.pushUrl`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Navigation#pushUrl). Here's how it would look in your code:

```
GotResponse result ->
    case result of
        Ok response ->
            ( { model | response = response }
            , Browser.Navigation.pushUrl model.key "/"
            )

        Err _ ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

---

You should have the [`Key`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Navigation#Key) in your model, which is required by the Elm runtime to make sure you're using `Browser.application` (which is explained [here](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Navigation#Key))

Comment: Thank you so much!
But this is what I already tried. It just stays in the same page (doesnt render to root page (I call it TopPage in my application))
Anyways you can suggest??

Comment: Are you handling `onUrlChange` in your code? If you aren't sure, please update your question with a link to the rest of your code!